# Push UIViewController onto another

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I can't seem to push a UITableViewController onto a UIViewController using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cardsViewController animated:YES];
```

The following code works for modally presenting the same view:

```
[self presentModalViewController:cardsViewController animated:YES];
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.
Ricky.

Comment: Is the code being called from a `UIViewController`?

Comment: is self.navigationController == nil?

Comment: conmulligan, it is being called from a view controller. David, the navigationController isn't nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricky,

Try this code:

```
if(self.navigationController == nil) NSLog(@"I am nil");
```

It will display "I am nil" in the console.

Comment: Sorry all. I didn't load my table view controller as the navigation's root controller properly. Ricky.